# Are questions about missing type identifiers (or a lack of understanding of which data type to use) off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

Consider the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42094347/2415822

On the surface, the OP is just missing a type identifier (`: Data?`), so I would argue that this question should be closed with the reason "This question was caused by ... **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Looking deeper, however, it's clear that the OP didn't even know which data type to use, as they say "I tried sting and int both not work."

Does this question still qualify for closure as a typo?  If not, is there a close reason which would be more appropriate?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to find a canonical for these questions.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I don't think closing as a typographical error is the correct action for that question as the OP simply didn't know the correct data type to use. It could be argued that it's unclear, but on the other hand, it got an answer, which you agree on being correct I assume, so it was clear enough to someone.

With a bit of editing, I believe the question *could* be useful to future users, but I'm not familiar with the tech that it's tagged under otherwise I'd edit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  From [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274334/2415822), "Stack Overflow is for *professional* programming questions. It should be expected that you at least know the basics of the programming language you're using."  Would you argue that knowing which data type to use is a language basic that should be expected of the asker?

Comment: A non-obvious syntax error may still be useful for future viewers. I don't know enough about this language to make a call, but "professional" doesn't mean "expert". Professional programmers are often called upon to learn new languages.

Comment: @JAL "Would you argue that knowing which data type to use is a language basic that should be expected of the asker?" -- That is highly dependent on the type and on the language.

Comment: The question basically boils down to "What's the return type of jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation()?", so it's not terribly useful since the answer can be found in the documentation, but that's beside the point - the point remains that it's not a typo question or an "I forgot to include the type annotation" question.

Comment: @BoltClock Is there a valid close reason for a question like that?  Or is closing not appropriate, and maybe a downvote due to the question being low quality instead?

Comment: @JAL: No close reason for it.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, that's really helpful to know.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that working the Swift tag (like I do) there seems to be a large amount of VLQ newbie questions (more than most other tags?), I don't find this to be one of them.

It fits the MCVE model, some research was done, a good answer was given - and most of all, while you had to dig into the comments on the answer, @rmaddy gave a very good *way* to look for the answer on your own in the future.

Another way to look at this:

In 2011 when I was trying to pick up Objective-C, Xcode IDE, UIKit Frameworks, et. al. it was very, um, challenging. The documentation from Apple was obtuse, Xcode was *finally* gaining a "unified" IDE, and I found Objective-C way too wordy for my tastes. So in 2014 when Swift came out I gave it another shot (I program in C# and ABAP for a living) and was floored by the amount of SO knowledge out there.

Nowadays I know how to use Xcode to find out what data type a `jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation` is using Xcode, but others don't. Sure, this is a newbie question. It may even be something answered if *the correct question was asked*.

But was this a vague question? Lacking MCVE or "what have you tried" or "what is your expectations"? At most, it has a more effective answer buried in the comments. But that isn't the fault of the OP.