# Questions on information sources

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

This is a follow up of one of the threads in the [How does one distinguish typos from coding errors in questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410808/how-does-one-distinguish-typos-from-coding-errors-in-questions) topic.

Many people there said *"One should first read the book on basics and only after that ask questions."*

At the same time one of the first rules on SO is not to ask for books and other sources. So, if the area quite a new for the person, what is the way for them to know which book to start with? It is hard to areas where there are only few books and this even harder for a newbie for areas where are tons of books. Any way to handle this on SO? If I am new for some area (let's say, in programming), where can I ask where to get the basics?

I searched a little bit through the SO and the led me to the second part of this question.

The rules for SO (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) say:

> **Some questions that fit into one of the categories listed above may be closed by the community because they aren't generally a good fit here or need additional information:**
> [...]
> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

How, then the pages like [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/) could survive? Don't get me wrong, I like and fully support the page, the question is "how can survive the page that violates SO rule? And why won't survive my own asking for alike?

Comment: It survives because it is very old and it's still actively maintained.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355588/1426539

Comment: "At the same time one of the first rules on SO is not to ask about books and other sources" - citation needed. Seen this happen several times without a problem

Comment: ... unless you meant "ask _for_ books and other sources", in which case you're right.

Comment: You can ask where to get the basics _somewhere else_. Reddit, Quora, dev.to, ... Here you can check the relevant tag wiki (many have resources, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) or ask in chat, but SO is deliberately not designed to accept every possible question.

Comment: @Zoe, a subtle difference for not a native speaker (me), thank you for catching this, fixed. Of course, I meant "for".

Comment: @jonrsharpe, is it related to whole SO ecosystem (Physics, Math, etc.) or to SO for programming only? It is really inconvenient to use so many networks for almost the same questions. Although, I see your point.

Comment: "It is really inconvenient to use so many networks for almost the same questions." I'm not sure that's true for questions asked on Stack Overflow, Seasoned Advice or Beer, Wine & Spirits, for example.

Comment: @DamirTenishev - Read the help center for the community you are interested in.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the internet. It is not meant to be. Nor is it a substitute for a good librarian. Maybe you live in a place which doesn't have a library or librarians in which case my heart goes out to you. They are great resources for finding books. In any case, there's also Amazon and other booksellers which deliver books almost everywhere on the planet. Searching on those is another avenue to find books. Basically, Stack Overflow is just not the place for everything.